# C# equivalent to Java's Instant class and RsaSHA256Signer class

Tags: java, c#, java.time.instant

I am trying to convert some java source code to C#.

What is the equivalent of the following Java classes in c#:

- RsaSHA256Signer
- [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)

Thank you

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of `RsaSHA256Signer`, because it is not in the Java SE API.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but it might be the following.

1. RSACryptoServiceProvider

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2008/08/25/using-rsacryptoserviceprovider-for-rsa-sha256-signatures/ for RsaSHA256Signer

So code will look like that :

```
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(data, "SHA256");
        if (rsa.VerifyData(data, "SHA256", signature))
        {
              Console.WriteLine("RSA-SHA256 signature verified");
        }
         else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RSA-SHA256 signature failed to verify");
        }
    }
```

2. The equivalent package to java.time will be System.DateTime

For example:

Java:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

C#:

```
DateTime localDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netframework-4.8

Additionally, you can look for [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) which is a popular library.

Comment: I would suggest changing `DateTime.Now` to `DateTime.UtcNow`, given that `Instant.now()` isn't affected by the system-local time zone, but `DateTime.Now` is.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Your suggestion is a better fit. Updated my answer accordingly.